# Why I have this Error during XSLT transformation: XSLT transformation failed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml, xslt

I am trying to dynamically create an additional element based on the content of the cooking
time element. I also Sort recipe data by cooking time and recipe name to display the additional elements.

**If the cooking time is greater than sixty minutes, the new element should display the words Slow Burner. If the cooking time is less than or equal to sixty minutes, and greater than or equal to thirty minutes, this new element should display the words Medium Burner. Otherwise, the new element should display the words Quick and Easy.**

I am getting a error and I don't understand why the if statement is not working.

Why?

The XSL is here:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/collection">
        <html>

        </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can use XSLT-2.0? Because it seems that you intend to use your stylesheet in a browser environment...

Comment: yes I'm sure about the XSLT-2.0. thanks

Comment: You say you're getting an error, so give us a clue - tell us what the error is. We enjoy solving puzzles, but there's no need to make them more difficult by withholding information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your loop to the following. The location of the `recipe` element has been changed to be included in the corresponding `table` (Of course, change it back if neccessary).

```
<xsl:for-each select="recipe">
    <xsl:sort select="cooking_Time" />
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="number(replace(cooking_Time,'minutes',''))" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </h4>
        </td>
        <td>
            <recipe>
                <xsl:value-of select="if ($time > 60) then 'Slow Burner' else if ($time >= 30) then 'Medium Burner' else 'Quick and Easy'" />
            </recipe>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="servings" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="preparetion_Time" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="cooking_Time" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="passiveTime" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="difficulty" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="ingredients">
                <xsl:for-each select="ingredient">
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This sorts the elements by `cooking_Time` (You had the `xsl:sort` at the wrong place; it has to immediately follow the `xsl:for-each`).

The main logic is in this expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="if ($time > 60) then 'Slow Burner' else if ($time >= 30) then 'Medium Burner' else 'Quick and Easy'" />
```

It outputs the appropriate string depending on the value of the `$time` variable (which was created to simplify the expression). The `fn:replace` in the variable

```
<xsl:variable name="time" select="number(replace(cooking_Time,'minutes',''))" />
```

takes care that the value of the `$time` variable is always a number and doesn't  contain the string "minutes".

---

If you cannot use XSLT-2.0, you can, alternatively, use this XSLT-1.0 solution:

```
<xsl:for-each select="recipe">
    <xsl:sort select="normalize-space(cooking_Time)" />
    <xsl:variable name="time">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(cooking_Time,'minutes')">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(substring-before(cooking_Time,'minutes'))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="number(cooking_Time)">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(cooking_Time)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- This value represents any items that don't have a 'cooking_Time' value present -->
                <xsl:value-of select="0" />
            </xsl:otherwise>                                
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h4>
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </h4>
        </td>
        <td>
            <recipe>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$time &gt; 60">
                        <xsl:text>Slow Burner</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$time &gt;= 30 and $time &lt;= 60">
                        <xsl:text>Medium Burner</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$time &lt; 30">
                        <xsl:text>Quick and Easy</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:text>Undefined</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </recipe>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="servings" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="preparetion_Time" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="cooking_Time" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="passiveTime" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="difficulty" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="ingredients">
                <xsl:for-each select="ingredient">
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It improves the sorting by using `normalize-space(...)` and uses `xsl:choose` instead of inline `if`s.

Comment: Firefox now shows this massage: Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called. Ok I understand now about the xsl:sort. what I don't understand is why the if statement is inside double quotes ?

Comment: I explicitly asked you if you could use XSLT-2.0, and you said "YES". Running this stylesheet in Firefox is impossible, because Firefox only supports XSLT-1.0.

Comment: Wait for some minutes.... I'm creating an XSLT-1.0 solution that should work in Firefox.

Comment: I'm confused Firefox shows this massage. Could the issue be the **name="time"** that is Unkown?

Comment: I'm only using Firefox because is the only browser that shows error message. google chrome shows a white empty page.

Comment: I added an XSLT-1.0 solution that should work in Firefox. Chrome is dubious, still.

Comment: It works.. I really appreciate your help, Thank you a lot.

Comment: May I ask you? About the attributes **unit="minutes"** I couldnt find any good source online explaining how to show the number in minutes in xslt

Comment: `unit="minutes"` is no standardized XML entity. In a good XML file, this attribute would indicate that the unit is =minutes and the trailing ` minutes` of the value would be omitted. Hence I did the trick of removing the "minutes" string from the input if it is present.

Comment: A standard way to codify minutes would be the time [duration](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#duration). You can find more info [here at W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-minutes-from-duration).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a LONG time since I've messed with XSL, but my guess would be that you're treating a string "30 minutes" as if it were a number: `if cooking_time >= 30`. If that's the case, one possible workaround would be to include a numeric duration in an attribute within the XML:

```
<cooking_time duration="30" unit="minutes">30 minutes</cooking_time>
```

Also, it may have been a copy/paste issue, but this doesn't look right:

```
cooking_Time &gt; -or- > 30 &lt; 60
```

Comment: hmm I see. ill try this and see if works.  I found this from this website http://faculty.madisoncollege.edu/schmidt/xml/xmlcond.html